# Enviar archivo por petición POST de AngularJS a un servicio Web Api

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

En mi FrontEnd tengo `<input id="file" ng-model="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().SelectedFile()" type="file" aria-label="disabled" />` y cuando elijo el archivo se ejecuta la función **SelectedFile()** en la cual tomo el archivo con **var value = document.getElementById("file").files[0];** el cual quisiera enviar por una petición POST hacia mi servicio y tomar el archivo con `HttpRequest request = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];` del lado del BackEnd

Answer (score 1):

mira puedes implementarlo como tu prefieras:

- 1.- Utiliza la dependencia de un tercero para AngularJS  llamada 'naif.base64'
  repositorio:https://github.com/adonespitogo/angular-base64-upload 
  ejemplo: http://embed.plnkr.co/MTzfQASN8ZVeocAq7VcM/preview
- 2.- o programarlo tu mismo en AngularJS con un poco de javascrip:

en tu vista:

```
    <input type="file" style="width: 200px;" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().selectFile(this)">
```

en tu controlador:

```
    $scope.fr = new FileReader();
    $scope.base64 = {};
    $scope.jsonRequest={};
    $scope.selectFile = function(element) {
    if (element.files.length === 0)
      return;
    $scope.fr.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);
    $scope.fr.onload = function () {
      $scope.$apply(function($scope) {
        $scope.base64 = $scope.fr.result;
        //para sacar unicamente el base64:
        $scope.jsonRequest.base64 = $scope.fr.result.split(",")[1];
        //o crear el objeto json a enviar:
        //{base64: "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4RDgRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAA…uZ3L2rf8AH5H/ANe1v/6JSijVv+PyP/r2t/8A0SlFMk//2Q==", type: "image/jpeg"}
        $scope.jsonRequest.type = $scope.fr.result.split(",")[0].split(":")[1].split(';')[0];
        console.log($scope.jsonRequest);
      });
    };
    $scope.fr.onerror = function (error) {
      console.error('Error: ', error);
    };
}
```

Teniendo tu objeto json con el base64 del archivo solo faltaria hacer la petición al web service

En el backend en mi caso con nodejs uso lo siguiente:

```
    var fs = require('fs');
    if (req.body.base64!= null && req.body.base64.length != 0) {
      var bitmap = new Buffer(req.body.base64, 'base64');
      var url_save_img = 'img/profile/' + "aquí el nombre segun tu lógica"+ ".png";
      fs.writeFileSync(url_save_img, bitmap);
    }
```

en mi caso solo estoy guardando puras imágenes y todas .png.
Espero y te sirva saludos!

Comment: Ya lo había resuelto, pero muchas gracias, saludos.